# SOQL - Obtaining Record Type Name

Tags: soql, case, record-type

We have several record types in our Case implementation.

I am able to get the **record typeid only** with the following.

```
SELECT Id,RecordTypeId FROM Case
```

If I try this, it is giving me an error.

```
SELECT Id,RecordTypeId,RecordTypeName FROM Case
```

I believe, *I am new to SF so I am not sure*, that we should be able to query the record type name of the case also in a SOQL.

Can someone tell me how to do that ?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

It's `RecordType.Name`

RecordTypes are held in separate [reference table](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/api/Content/sforce_api_objects_recordtype.htm) so to query the names just treat the `RecordTypeId` as any other lookup field :)

In case you've never used the "dot notation" (the way SOQL handles relationships and things that would be JOINs in regular databases): http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/dbcom_soql_sosl/Content/sforce_api_calls_soql_relationships.htm